# VS2010 Extension for generating Equality overrides a la ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I'm not the big ReSharper fan. But the code generation tool to generate equality overrides (Equals, GetHashCode) is a huge timesaver!

Does anyone know if there's an extension for Visual Studio 2010 that does the same?

This is what ReSharper generates:

[image: ReSharper's code]

Comment: What is it about Resharper you don't like? I personally think it's a fantastic tool and can't live without it, but I am interested in your views.

Comment: Basically, I think it hides/replaces some of the native VS features that I like. And the replacement is not as good IMHO. It also shows a lot of warnings (highlighted by curly underline) in places it shouldn't. It's useless for Web development (which is what I do the most). But - it is also because I just haven't used it enough to get used to it. And to be honest, I don't want to get used to it. And one more. It's slow as hell. On my own machine it's no problem. But I work at different places now and then, and company PCs tend to be 2-3 yrs old.

Comment: Take a look at Resharper 6.1 as it has a lot more native support for web stuff. Also the performance should have been improved, however peoples setups very greatly. A lot of the curly underlines can be configured not to be shown at all, but they are usually indicating that there are problems with your code that need to be fixed :)

Comment: Yer, I know what they mean. But sometimes I don't agree, heck - sometimes FXCop doesn't agree. If you ought to fix every single line, you'd never get anything done.

Comment: yeah, FXCop can be a bit OTT! I just use Resharper with StyleCop (with tweaked rules) and these help me greatly to produce clean, consistant code.

Comment: ReSharper only hides/replaces the native VS features for which it provides better alternatives. Which ones do you miss?

Comment: I don't know exactly. One thing I hate, is the "documentation" tooltips. They're worse IMHO. And I'd still argue that it's crap for web development. It actually destroys JS intellisense. And VS11 will have much better editing experience for JavaScript, so I doubt it's gonna beat that. This was not meant to be a discussion whether or not to use ReSharper. But since there's no answer to my question, I guess there's no VS extension that generates equality overrides.

Comment: Crap for web development? Just as a hint, consider watching [these](http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/aspnet-features-in-resharper-5-part-1) [two](http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/aspnet-features-in-resharper-5-part-2) videos

Comment: Video #1: Searching an ~80 line file? It's much quicker and easier to just memorize its structure. If you can't do that, good luck with everything. If I need to search, CTRL + F, begin typing and what I need is highlighted in yellow. The file generation features, shows exactly what I mean: The native equivalent in VS2010, is much, much better.

Comment: Video #2: Same as #1. Why are they not using the mvcaction code snippet for writing it? I thought the tool was about productivity... Highlighting a view name 'cause it doesn't exist? You'll already know anyway :) And the huge point of web development they're totally ignoring: CSS & JavaScript. Seriously, ReSharper bloats the intellisense in JavaScript with all sorts of crap you don't want. And the stuff you do want (IntelliSense for your own code) is *gone*! What's up with that? Seriously. We don't have to agree on this. But I'm not a fan of ReSharper for a bunch of obvious reasons :)

Comment: I don't want to wade into a religious war, but I do want to point out that ReSharper allows you to disable warnings as you see fit, by going to ReSharper/Options/Code Inpsections/Inspection Severity.  You can change any rule from Error (red) to Warning (yellow), hint (green), or suggestion (no icon).

Comment: Me neither :) I just don't want to buy a tool, and then disable a bunch of features. Not worth it.